# making a partialMock work with incorrect argument

Tags: php, laravel, testing, mocking, phpunit

I am using the following laravel code to make a partial mock.

```
$mock = $this->partialMock(Service::class, function (MockInterface $mock) { $mock->shouldReceive('process')->with('some string'); });
```

If the value received by process() is 'some string' then the mocked version of the process function runs and the expectation passes. As it should

However if a string other than 'some string' is passed to process() then the real version of the process function runs.

This is not what I want. I want a partial mock that mocks the process function regardless of what argument it receives and passes if it receives the expected value and fails if it receives any other value.

I cant use andRecieveAnyValue() function ( or whatever it is ) because this will always mock process() will never result in a fail if the wrong string is recieved.

Comment: What you are looking for is not a mock but a [spy](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/spies.html?highlight=spies).

Comment: is there such a thing as a partial spy?

Comment: Im not sure a spy is what i am looking for since i need to make sure the code in the partially mocked function DOES NOT run

Comment: Do you need to run part of the class? Or are you just trying to see if the method you mocked is run? If you need to run the class but also mock part of the class, then yes, a Mock is the way, but if you are trying to make sure if your code calls a method with some parameters and just that, you don't want to run any class' code, then a Spy is your solution. Tell me what of these 2 possibilities are you testing and I will help you.